# Operator overloading with templates

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

Im trying to run a program with templates using operator < ,> methods, im getting a compiler error telling me **"instantiated from here"** and **cannot convert `Temps<double>' to`double' in return** ,,The problem starts when i call the operator function Heres the code..

```
    template <class T>
class Temps
{   
 private:   
 T a;

 public:
 Temps()
 {
 }
 Temps(T b)
 {
   a=b;
         }     
 T operator<(Temps c)
 {
   if (a < c.a)
   {
      return *this;
   }
   return c;        
 } 
 T operator>(Temps c)              
   {
      if (a > c.a)
      {
         return *this;
      }

      return c;                 
   }   

};

int main()
{

    double d1 = -9.002515,d2=98.321,d3=1.024;

    Temps<double>mag(d1);
    Temps<double>lag(d3);
    Temps<double>tag;
    tag=mag < lag;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use `<` to find the max. `<` should return `bool`.

Comment: That must be the weirdest semantics for a `<` operator I've ever seen.

Comment: Please don't do this. This kind of abuse of operator overloading is exactly the reason why operator overloading has such a bad reputation in some circles. Would it be so bad to have a `max` and a `min` unction for this instead of an operator which the casual reader of your code expects to do something completely different from what it does?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `<` and `>` functions return a `T`, but you are trying to return a `Temps<T>`. What you probably want to return is either `a` or `c.a`. But the normal semantics of `<` and `>` is to return a `bool`, so you may want to return `a < c.a` for `<`:

```
bool operator <(Temps c) { return a < c.a; }
```

Similar for `>`.

Comment: @drwilcox maybe tell OP to return return a instead of this